# Parsing XML into a label

Tags: xml, swift

I'm using Swift 2.0, with Kanna, with the code I have at the moment I can print the correct code but I cannot put it into a label, can anyone help?

The code I'm using at the moment is:

```
 if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (NSURL(string: "the_site_url")!), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {


            // Search for nodes by XPath
            for link in doc.xpath("/html/body/center/div[@id='calloutHeader']/div[@id='mainContentSideBG']/div[@id='mainContentBG']/div[@id='mainContent']/div[@id='mainLoop']/div[@id='post-21557']/h2[@class='entry-title']/a") {
                print(link.text)
                print(link["href"])
            }
```

Comment: Never mind, was able to do this by doing self.[labelname].text = link.text

Comment: If you solved your issue you should delete the question or if you think it will help future readers, post a proper answer.